# Finite Engel group is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

A group $G$ is said to be $n$ engel if

$$[x,[x, \dots ,[x,y]]\dots ]=1,$$

where $x$ appears $n$ times, and this holds for all $x,y\in G$.

We know there is infinite order engel group which is not nilpotent.

> But what can we say about finite order engel groups, are they always nilpotent?

Comment: Actually, I was studying about the Engel groups and this question arises that weather finite $n$ Engel groups are nilpotent or not.

Comment: The answer is YES (Zorn, 1936), see http://www.groupsstandrews.org/2009/Talks/Traustason.pdf

Comment: #Nicky Hekster thanks for the reply, $groupsstandrews.org/2009/Talks/Traustason.pdf$ here only statement is given please tell me that how to prove this result.

Comment: You can find a proof in the book of Derek J.S. Robinson - A Course in the Theory of Groups. The proof runs as follows: take a minimal counterexample, then every proper subgroup is nilpotent, whence solvable by a famous Theorem of Schmidt (also to be found in the book of Robinson). Then the Hirsch-Plotkin radical (the unique maximal local nilpotent subgroup) equals $G$, which means that $G$ is nilpotent, since it is finite. Please look up the details in the book.

Comment: Thank you, sir.

Comment: You are welcome, by the way, I found the original abstract here: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183498976 (scroll down).

Comment: This looks like a reasonable request about the state of knowledge concerning a research topic rather than a "here is my problem solve it for me" question, so I would not vote for closing it for lack of context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So that this question does not remain listed as unanswered, and for the benefit of any future readers, I will provide an answer. 
This follows the suggestions in the comments of Nicky Hekster, to look at the exposition in  *Derek J.S. Robinson - A Course in the Theory of Groups*.

In Robinson this result is

> **Theorem 12.3.4 (Zorn)** A finite Engel group is nilpotent.

To prove it, we need to recall the following: *(For the benefit of the reader I shall include the same numbering as in Robinson so that the proofs for these may be looked up if you wish).*

**Notation and preliminaries**: $L(G)$ is the set of left Engel elements of $G$. If $G$ is an Engel group then $G=L(G)$. 
The [Hirsch-Plotkin radical](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Hirsch-Plotkin_radical) of $G$ is the unique maximal normal locally nilpotent subgroup, I will denote this as $HP(G)$. The [Fitting subgroup](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Fitting_subgroup) is the subgroup generated by all the normal nilpotent subgroups of a group $G$ and is written $Fit(G)$. Note that if $G$ is finite then $Fit(G)$ is nilpotent, and in particular in the case $G$ is finite, if $G=Fit(G)$ we can conclude $G$ is nilpotent.

We also need the following two Theorems:

> **Theorem 9.1.9 (O.J Schmidt)** Assume that every maximal subgroup of a
>   finite group $G$ is nilpotent but $G$ itself is not nilpotent. Then
>   $G$ is soluble. <sub><sup>*(Note that the theorem says more than this but we do
>   not need the rest)*</sup></sub>.

and

> **Theorem 12.3.3 (Gruenberg)**. Let $G$ be a soluble group. Then $L(G)$ coincides with the Hirsch-Plotkin radical. <sub><sup>*(Note that the
>   theorem says more than this but we do not need the rest)*</sup></sub>

We can now prove the result.

**Proof of Theorem 12.3.4**

Suppose that this is false. Then let $G$ be a minimal counter example, that is, $G$ is a finite Engel group with smallest order subject to being not nilpotent. Thus every proper subgroup of $G$ must be nilpotent. Thus $G$ is soluble by the Theorem of Schmidt.  Then by the Theorem of Gruenberg above, we know that if $G$ is soluble then $L(G)$ coincides with the Hirsch-Plotkin radical. Since $G$ is finite, the Hirsch-Plotkin radical of $G$ coincides with the Fitting subgroup of $G$, and since $G$ is Engel we know that $G=L(G)$. Thus we have $$G=L(G)=HP(G)=Fit(G).$$ Thus $G$ must be nilpotent. $\square$